# Laptop not connecting to WiFi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, laptop

I have a DELL [Inspiron 15 5577](https://topics-cdn.dell.com/pdf/inspiron-15-5577-gaming-laptop_Service-Manual_en-us.pdf) laptop with an Intel 3165AC + BT4.2 [802.11ac + Bluetooth 4.2, Dual Band 2. 4&5 GHz, 1x1] WiFi modem.

Its WiFi signal is very weak; it's not even catching access points which are far away. I have tried the following:
1. I have updated all the software. I have uninstalled and then reinstalled the software. This step didn't improved the condition.
2. I have opened my laptop, removed the chip set and inserted the chip set of another healthy laptop but the condition did not elevated.
3. I have tried to put my Wireless Adapter Settings to Maximum Performance I am now very confused as what could be the issue. I am looking for a solution.

PS:
I have this problem on every WiFi I have. I have tried my phone's WiFi, my college WiFi, my friends and so on. I have made my phone an access point or tried access point available in my college but it didn't worked. I would like to mention that my other devices(like my friends laptop or my phone) can connect to the access points like in my college but the problem persist with me only.

I have my phone's hotpot currently active and its like 5cm away from my laptop. My laptop is showing full connection. If i move my phone to a meter(approximately or less than) the signal weakens to 1 bar to even zero. This problem is from every access point no matter the configuration or the channel.

As an example here, I have made my phone as an access point and these are the results:

So I have clicked a picture of my connection and as you may see I can't be more than 15cm away from it.[Full WiFi connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8ija.jpg)

Distance [distance of laptop and access point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSTFY.jpg)

WiFi connectivity after is: [Connectivity with distance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xK5xQ.jpg)

I am myself a CSE 2nd year student so I would love to learn the technical also. Please Help!!

Comment: Is the antenna (probably more than one) properly connected to the Wifi module?

Comment: Yes. I have connected the wires properly. About 3 4 times. WiFi is poor but still if a device is very close <1m its showing it was 1 or maybe 2 bars.

Comment: An external USB WiFi adapter can be found for US$3 to $15 (more expensive ones have external antennae, which probably increase range), e.g. https://www.walmart.com/ip/Netis-WF-2120-Netis-WF2120-IEEE-802-11n-Wi-Fi-Adapter-for-Desktop-Computer-Notebook-USB-150-Mbit-s-2-48-GHz-ISM-External/37406394 and https://www.amazon.com/EDUP-ac600Mbps-Wireless-External-10-6-10-13/dp/B01CCMUN8C/ref=sr_1_3 .

Comment: It is odd that the wireless is working but the connection is just very weak. Try updating the bios.

Comment: "I have this problem on every WiFi I have. I have tried my phone's WiFi, my college WiFi, my friends and so on." Do all devices have problems connecting to the router or access point, or are you just unable to connect from your Inspiron to them? Please click [edit] & clarify that point. Also, what's the make/model of yr WiFi router/access point? On which channel? (check with this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.farproc.wifi.analyzer ) What's its SNR? (app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.javali.wifisnr )  Pls click [edit] & add that data to question.

Answer (score 0):

Hey everyone it's me who is having this problem from a different account. I finally fixed it and I would like to share how I did it.

I opened my laptop(completely). As I have mentioned in my question above, I have tried all the software related issues. After marking all the points today, I got to the conclusion that the Antenna is the only thing which is not checked.

I went to a shop nearby of scrap and purchased broken laptop cabinets. There I found the Antenna. I picked the one which were looking like mine or were from mine. I took 5 of them.

After coming home, I tried all 5 Antenna and in the 3rd one, my WiFi condition elevated and it came to normal.

**Hence the reason was: Antenna was not good.**

I would like to mention that:
1. The Antenna which was previously connected to the chip set in my laptop was broken.
2. If you are gonna do this, first open your laptop under a professional if it's your first day. It took me from 12:00 noon to 10:00pm.
3. First try for software and the try chip set from another computer, if the problem persist, go for this solution but instead of opening the laptop, connect antenna externally. If it works externally, then try to move it into the machine.

Thank you all.

PS: 
Antenna of used laptop are very cheap and you'll not feel to spend anything on them.
The model DELL Inspiron 5577 has this problem and it's very common. The WiFi Antenna breaks in no time. That's a pain I know.
Do not open your laptop for the first time without a guide or a mentor.
First try all externally before taking the decision to open your laptop.